# phpmyadmin ubuntu 14.04 login with no visible error displayed

Tags: ubuntu, login, phpmyadmin

I had working Phpmyadmin installed on Ubuntu 14.04 after some mysql installation I also reconfigured phpmyadmin. After that I am not able to login when I login with the root and the correct password that was set during the installation it refreshes and doesn't give any errors

It takes me to the following url
mysite/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=5d8a89f30dc3804be2ee68e5dfa52382

Even if I use wrong password or username it won't give any errors.
How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs?

Comment: What exactly did you do for the the reconfiguration? Do you mean with the package manager, like `dpkg-reconfigure`? Can you connect from the command-line client like `mysql -u root -p`?